# List 130. Surrounded Regions leetcode solution using bfs

Tags: python, algorithm

> Given a 2D board containing 'X' and 'O' (the letter O), capture all
>   regions surrounded by 'X'.
>
> A region is captured by flipping all 'O's into 'X's in that surrounded
>   region.

Input:

```
X X X X
X O O X
X X O X
X O X X
```

Output:

```
X X X X
X X X X
X X X X
X O X X
```

All I am doing is to traverse all the edges and set all of them to `x_not_possible` and also there connected neighbors. Connected neighbors are found by doing bfs.

Traverse once more and set `x_not_possible` back to `O` and all the nodes not set to `x_not_possible` to `X`.

Code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def solve(self, board):
        if not board:
            return

        row_len, col_len = (len(board), len(board[0]))
        if row_len == 1 and col_len == 1:
            return

        def get_neighbours((i, j)):
            directions = []
            map_direction = {"left":(0, -1), "right":(0, 1), "up":(-1, 0), "down":(1, 0)}
            for _i, _j in map_direction.values():
                __i, __j = _i + i, _j + j
                if __i < row_len and __i >= 0 and __j < col_len and __j >= 0:
                    yield __i, __j

        increment_col, decrement_row, decrement_col, increment_row = (False, False, False, True)
        queue = []
        stop = [0, 0]
        while True:
            row, col = 0, 1
            if increment_row:
                if stop[row] + 1 >= row_len:
                    increment_col, increment_row = True, False
                    continue
                else:
                    stop[row] += 1
            elif increment_col:
                if stop[col] + 1 >= col_len:
                    decrement_row, increment_col = True, False
                    continue
                else:
                    stop[col] += 1
            elif decrement_row:
                if stop[row] - 1 < 0:
                    decrement_col, decrement_row = True, False
                    continue
                else:
                    stop[row] -= 1
            elif decrement_col:
                if stop[col] - 1 < 0:
                    break
                else:
                    stop[col] -= 1
            i, j = stop
            if board[i][j] == "O":
                queue.append((i, j))

        while len(queue):
            i, j = queue.pop()
            board[i][j] = "x_not_possible"
            for k, l in get_neighbours((i, j)):
                if board[k][l] == "O":
                    board[k][l] = "x_not_possible"
                    queue.append((k, l))

        for i in range(row_len):
            for j in range(col_len):
                if board[i][j] == "O":
                    board[i][j] = 'X'
                elif board[i][j] == "x_not_possible":
                    board[i][j] = 'O'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Review

There are a few things that could be improved upon.

**1 .Your `get_neighbours` could use some love**

`map_direction = {"left":(0, -1), "right":(0, 1), "up":(-1, 0), "down":(1, 0)}`

I might understand using a dictionary so you can see which value corresponds to which direction, but this may be simplified to just using a tuple of directions.

`_i` and `__i` are variables badly named I believe, maybe `new_i` or something would be better. `_i` and `__i` implies that these variables are private/protected, and in your case they are not.

*Secondly I think with this:*

`increment_col, decrement_row, decrement_col, increment_row = (False, False, False, True)`

You reinvent your `get_neighbours`

**2. Use enumerate**

I think this was said in your last question you posted on CR too, and it is still valid. You should defenitly use enumerate when possible, see the corresponding [PEP article](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/)

**3. Doing this in one loop**

You have:

- A `while True:` loop
- Another `while` loop

This could be done in one loop, by tracking if any of the current visited vertex in the dfs, are in either the last or first (row or collumn)

## Alternative code

```
def get_neighbours(board, position):
    directions = ((0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0))
    for direction in directions:
        new_x, new_y = (p+d for d, p in zip(direction, position))
        if new_x in range(0, len(board) - 1) and new_y in range(0, len(board[0]) - 1):
            yield new_x, new_y

def dfs(board, start):
    visited, stack = set(), [start]
    change = True

    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex not in visited:
            if change and (vertex[0] in (0, len(board) - 1) or vertex[1] in (0, len(board[0]) - 1)):
                change = False                
            visited.add(vertex)
            for x, y in get_neighbours(board, vertex):
                if (x, y) not in visited  and board[x][y] == "O":
                    stack.append((x, y))
    return visited, change

def solve(board):
    visited = set()

    # Group the O's
    for x, row in enumerate(board):
        for y, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == 'O' and (x, y) not in visited:
                group, change = dfs(board, (x, y))
                visited |= group
                if change:
                    for o in group:
                        board[o[0]][o[1]] = "X"

    return board

if __name__ == '__main__':
    board = [["X", "X", "X", "X"],
             ["X", "O", "O", "X"],
             ["X", "X", "O", "X"],
             ["X", "O", "X", "X"]]
    print(solve(board))
```